# Manga - woman is sent back in time, gets poisoned, cures herself

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

It's a manga about a time travelling female lead (FL).

The FL is a herbal doctor - or something like that, maybe she studied Chinese medicine - in the modern era. She travelled to ancient times (maybe due to a plane crash) into the body of a general's daughter, who dies from poisoning on her wedding day. The FL travels to the general's daughter's wedding day and realises that she has been poisoned, so she treats herself.
All her (the general's daughter) family study medicine and they work for the imperial family .
Everyone thought that she was useless and ugly and she had been bullied by them .
Until the FL come and prove the opposite.

This is all I remember exactly about the manga; the rest in my memory is a little blurry.
I read it about 1 year ago .

Comment: Welcome to the site! Roughly when did you read this? It may help us to eliminate newer stories.